# I could link the package with my project using 'npm-link'. But, Some how in the browser, the changes are not reflecting properly

Tags: npm-link

I have a component library [design-system]. I want to use that library in another project.
I did run `npm-link` in 'design-system' and `npm link design-system` in the project.

First, the link didn't work, after I deleted `package-lock.json` and did `npm i`. I could see, my component refers to the design system's dist index path. Even If I change anything in the design system and build it. It is reflecting immediately in the project. I can see the design-system's code in VS Code IDE.

But, when we run the program, the changes are not reflecting in the UI.

For example,
I commented on the `console.log` code in design-system

[image]

even I can see this code in the package by clicking 'Go to Definition'. But in the browser, the code is not updated.

[image]

I cleared 'Application cache' and tried again. I don't know what I am missing. Please help me with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the build in watch mode for your `design-system` library. Now for each change, the library will build and the bundle will update hence you will see the changes reflecting.

Alternatively, for development purposes, you can do something like

```
"design-system": "file:../relative-path-from-pkg-json"
```

instead of npm-link. still, if you can target the non-build version of your library. it may or may-not work deponding on your build tooling.

Or you can get real fancy and try [Nx Monorepo](https://nx.dev/) approach which will take care of everything about tooling. while you can focus on your development.